# PowerShell command to read multiple txt files that match a specific criteria into their content

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am beginner with power shell script and I want to get a loop command to be used in the SSIS environment.
There are multiples txt file in the same folder location that requires to capture and read only the files that match a criteria, based on the content of first line/ header, like a column names parameters.
The SSIS need to have a loop statement to read the file that match the criteria and move it to another folder with name like "files_read_completed".

The scenarios are the following as below, where only the FILE_2 does not contains Header/ columns names according to expected criteria.
And the location of files is the same for all : "C:\TEST\FILE*.txt"

FILE_1.txt Content:

```
COLUMN NAME 1 ; COLUMN NAME 2 ; COLUMN NAME 3 , OTHER COLUMNs
12345         ; TEST          ; 10
4567          ; TEST2         ; 20
```

FILE_2.txt Content:

```
999999        ; ABCD          ; 90
9999          ; ABCD2         ; 99
```

FILE_3.txt Content:

```
COLUMN NAME 1 ; COLUMN NAME 2 ; COLUMN NAME 3 ; OTHER COLUMNs

67890         ; NEW           ; 30
1010101       ; NEW1          ; 40
```

I want to read in this case only the files "FILE_1" and "FILE_3" in SSIS, because they match the criteria where first line of file start with -like "COLUMN NAME 1 ; COLUMN NAME 2*"
The script needs to capture only the path location, file name and extension that will be used in SSIS and then, write the data in the target table.

I have tried the below commands, after looking for alternatives in some forums, but with no successful.
Could someone provide any support to help here?

```
$FileName  = Get-Item "C:\TEST\FILE*.txt" | Select-Object Name

    ForEach($FirstRow in $FileName)
    {
        if($FirstRow [0] like "COLUMN NAME 1 ; COLUMN NAME 2*")
        {
            $UniqueFileName = Get-Item $FileName    
            Out-File $UniqueFileName
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're never reading the files content that's what your code is missing

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing reading the file's first line, for that you can use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2) with the [`-TotalCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-limit-the-number-of-lines-get-content-returns) parameter:

```
# get all files an enumerate them
Get-Item "C:\TEST\FILE*.txt" | Sort-Object CreationTime | ForEach-Object {
    # read the first line from each file
    $firstline = $_ | Get-Content -TotalCount 1
    # compare if the first line matches
    if($firstline -like "COLUMN NAME 1 ; COLUMN NAME 2*") {
        # if it does, output the the file's Absolute Path
        # if you just want to output the file's `Name`
        # instead of it's Path, you can do `$_.Name`
        $_.FullName
    }
} | Set-Content path\to\outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Hi Santiago, thanks for helping. It working fine.
I have included "1" in the end of "TotalCount", like Total Count 1 and worked.
In additional, I forgot to mention. How can I ordering the file by date, to show the older files firstly in the output file? The idea is to point to SSIS to capture the older one first.

Comment: @AuReMarks that was a typo on my part, sorry. I have updated the code, you can `Sort-Object CreationTime` re sorting from oldest to newest (see update)